# Is there any way to stop/resume file download from AWS S3 while using s3cmd?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I'm downloading a huge file from S3 (around 20 GB) using s3cmd and I wish to pause the download right now and resume it again tomorrow.

I've read about the `--continue` flag but I don't know about its usage. As in, should the download be ended in a specific way for the `--continue` flag to be able to resume it later on? Or will the `--continue` flag be able to resume download no matter how the process was stopped, regardless if it was a keyboard interrupt, accidental shutdown or network error.

Can somebody give an example?

The intended usage is with the `get` command and version of s3cmd is 2.0.2.

Comment: Side-note: These days, it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'll check it out. Does AWS CLI allow stop/resume?

Comment: I don't believe so. It runs synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, simply using the `continue` flag does the job splendidly. I ended the download by disconnecting the network. And then started again the next day using the `--continue` flag and it resumed the download from where it had left.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [s3api cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html) to get the object in parts. 
Look at the `--range` and `--part-number`.

While researching your question I came across something interesting. Ability to download S3 objects over [bittorrent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3Torrent.html).  However there are few caveats, the object should be less than 5GB and that it should be public.

Comment: +1 for sharing the bittorrent thing. Looks cool! Won't work for my current use case as the object is >5GB.