# How can I run s3cmd from anywhere, Windows 10

Tags: python, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I pip installed `s3cmd` into my `conda` environment. I would like to be able to run this script the way the guide shows https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd

i.e

```
s3cmd --configure
```

The .py file installed itself here:

```
C:\Users\me\miniconda3\envs\my_env\Scripts
```

Do I need to create a .bat file or something?

Comment: **Side-note:** These days, it's better to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

Comment: I want to resume downloads like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52410324/is-there-any-way-to-stop-resume-file-download-from-aws-s3-while-using-s3cmd